# Scaling Website to Fit Mobile Screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

So I'm working on a small website, http://www.liftlists.com, as a summer project just to get better at web design and programming. Everything is going great so far design wise, but I'm having a ton of trouble getting it to fit on mobile - it displays the full site every time. I've changed the .container to fluid, changed by tables to responsive, yet it still doesn't fit to mobile pages. I'm using Bootstrap, jQuery, and a bit of Angular to run the site.

What am I doing wrong here? I've looked at other questions but each one seems to have a slightly different problem.Thanks in advance!

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="liftscript.js"></script>
<script src="dropdown.js"></script>



<style>

body { 
    background-color: #516774;
}

    .container-fluid{
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 2cm;

    }

.large-background {
        background: url('big_background2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    }

    .nav_heading {
        background: #ededed;
        color: #222;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        display: none;

    }

    .below_heading {
        display: none;
    }

    ul.tabs{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background: #ededed;

    }

    ul.tabs li:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }


    ul.tabs li{
        background: none;
        color: #222;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

    ul.tabs li.active{
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.90);
        color: #222;
    }

    .tab-content{
        display: none;
        background: #ededed;
        padding: 5px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        margin-bottom:70px;
    }

    .tab-content.active{
        display: inherit;
    }

    .info {
    display: none;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);

}

    #button-float {
    float: right;
}

    .float {
    float: right;
}
    #inside_nav_heading {
    display: none;
    background: #ededed;
    color: #222;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;

}

    .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    color: white;
}

.ig-b- { 

    display: inline-block; 
}
.ig-b- img { 
    visibility: hidden; 

}
.ig-b-:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -60px; 
} 

.ig-b-:active { 

    background-position: 0 -120px; 

}
.ig-b-24 { 

    width: 24px; height: 24px; background: url(http://badges.instagram.com/static/images/ig-badge-sprite-24.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {

.ig-b-24 { 
    background-image: url(http://badges.instagram.com/static/images/ig-badge-sprite-24@2x.png); background-size: 60px 178px; 
}
```

Comment: .container-fluid - remove width 800px;  use max-width 800px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the .container to a fix width, it won't adapt.

Change this:

```
.container-fluid{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 2cm;

}
```

To this:

```
.container-fluid{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 2cm;
}
```

And it will adapt to screen until it reaches 800px, then it won't expand more.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a constrained width layout, could you not just use the prefixed .container class, instead of .container-fluid?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using twitter bootstrap framework for your frontend designs and that makes it very easy.

Just try and use the bootstrap columns, it is made for devices responsive designs.

Study this part on Bootstrap website ([Bootstrap Grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid))

If you implement it, your website will be responsive on all devices. :)